# I have enabled the ATS in plist

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I have enabled the ATS in plist.

**Expected** to see the error message for http call - App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app’s Info.plist file

**Actual** - Data does not load and not able to see the above error message.

Is there a way one could validate this scenario,Meaning i want to break at the point http is used.

Comment: I need to basically know which API is failing to load.Also i need to break at that API where http is used.Right now, am not getting the error where i am using http..What could be the reason that i am not getting the error.There could be many other places where http is used in project, and i might not get errors there also.

Comment: Can you provide the details of your ATS settings in your Info.plist?  By default, your app will have ATS enabled, so you shouldn't have anything in particular in you Info.plist related to ATS.  Also, you don't mention how you are loading data?  web view? NSURLSession? 3rd Party Library?